# Default first boot activity on Android 2.2?

Tags: android, tablet

I'm working on modifying a firmware/ROM for an unbranded Chinese Android tablet i got. When i flash it to the Tablet and get to the lockscreen, unlocking it starts the Setup Wizard - but there appear to be TWO - As Android asks me to choose between two activities - the Setup Wizard and some 'defaultActivity'.

So i wonder - Where and how is this controlled by Android to know what to launch on first boot?

Comment: just an idea: can you try to see with LogCat if any particular intent, like some "ACTION_FIRST_BOOT", is broadcasted?

Comment: I'll have a look later today. I'm pretty surei had a look at the logcat output and didn't see something odd, But i'm no Android expert yet. I'll capture it and link to a pastebin of it here just in case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove Provision.APK to get rid of the duplicate APK - According to Cyanogenmod's Barebones page it isnt needed. Not much of a proper solution, But thats all i could find lacking any kind of source code for this device.